# Correct use casting float to int for percentage?

Tags: objective-c

I'm using this code to attempt to convert a float to an int, then use it for UILabel text:

```
[progLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deck Progress %i%%",progBar.progress*100]];
```

and I've tried this:

```
[progLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deck Progress %i%%",(int)progBar.progress*100]];
```

The displayed text is always "0%".

I also tried this which works:

```
int pval=progBar.progress*100;
[progLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deck Progress %i%%",pval]];
```

I've tried  %f%%  but that gives me too many digits - I'm trying to get only 0-100, no decimal places.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `(int)(progBar.progress*100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(int)` is applied only to `progBar.progress` because casting has higher precedence than multiplication, and `(int)progBar.progress` is always 0 if 0 ≤ progBar.progress < 1. You need to cast the whole expression like

```
(int)(progBar.progress * 100)
```

Alternatively, you could avoid casting at all, by using a format of floating point which does not show the fractional part.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deck progress %.0f%%", progBar.progress * 100]
```

Comment: Thanks - I saw dasblinkenlight first - I can't check both but I can vote yours up.

Answer (score 1):

> The displayed text is always "0%".

This is because you are not *casting* the float to integer: you are passing a float to an unsuspecting function *expecting* an integer. You should add a cast:

```
[progLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deck Progress %i%%",(int)(progBar.progress*100)]];
```

Comment: Duh - thanks again. I'll check the answer as soon as allowed.